# Recursive function call hanging, Erlang

Tags: windows, memory, erlang, erlang-shell

I am currently teaching my self Erlang. Everything is going well until I found a problem with this function.

```
-module(chapter).
-compile(export_all).

list_length([])      ->   0;
list_length([_|Xs])  ->   1+list_length([Xs]).
```

This was taken out of an textbook. When I run this code using OTP 17, it just hangs, meaning it just sits as shown below.

```
1> c(chapter).
{ok,chapter}
2> chapter:list_length([]).
0
3> chapter:list_length([1,2]).
```

When looking in the task manager the Erlang OTP is using 200 Mb to 330 Mb of memory. What causes this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not terminating because you are creating a new non-empty list in every case: `[Anything]` is always a non-empty list, even if that list contains an empty list as its only member (`[[]]` is a non-empty list of one member).

A proper list terminates like this: `[ Something | [] ]`.

So with that in mind...

```
list_length([])      ->   0;
list_length([_|Xs])  ->   1 + list_length(Xs).
```

In most functional languages "proper lists" are cons-style lists. Check out [the Wikipedia entry on "cons"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) and [the Erlang documentation about lists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67044), and then meditate on examples of list operations you see written in example code for a bit.

**NOTES**

1. Putting whitespace around operators is a Good Thing; it will prevent you from doing confused stuff with arrows and binary syntax operators next to each other along with avoiding a few other ambiguities (and its easier to read anyway).
2. As Steve points out, the memory explosion you noticed is because while your function is recursive, it is not *tail recursive* -- that is, `1 + list_length(Xs)` leaves pending work to be done, which must leave a reference on the stack. To have anything to add 1 to it must complete execution of `list_length/1`, return a value, and in this case remember that pending value as many times as there are members in the list. Read Steve's answer for an example of how tail recursive functions can be written using an *accumulator* value.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP is learning Erlang, note also that the `list_length/1` function isn't amenable to [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) because of its addition operation, which requires the runtime to call the function recursively, take its return value, add 1 to it, and return the result. This requires stack space, which means that if the list is long enough, you can run out of stack.

Consider this approach instead:

```
list_length(L)           -> list_length(L, 0).
list_length([], Acc)     -> Acc;
list_length([_|Xs], Acc) -> list_length(Xs, Acc+1).
```

This approach, which is very common in Erlang code, creates an accumulator in `list_length/1` to hold the length value, initializing it to 0 and passing it to `list_length/2`, which does the recursion. Each call of `list_length/2` then increments the accumulator, and when the list is empty, the first clause of `list_length/2` returns the accumulator as the result. But note that the addition operation here occurs *before* the recursive call takes place, which means the calls are true tail calls and thus do not require extra stack space.

For non-beginner Erlang programmers, it can be instructive to compile both the original and modified versions of this module with `erlc -S` and examine the generated Erlang assembler. With the original version, the assembler contains `allocate` calls for stack space and uses `call` for recursive invocation, where `call` is the instruction for normal function calls. But for this modified version, no `allocate` calls are generated, and instead of using `call` it performs recursion using `call_only`, which is optimized for tail calls.